# MySQL reports syntax error, but I do not see it?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to run this query:

```
INSERT INTO table_a (fb_uid, from, to, time) VALUES (12345,'blah','test','2012-12-13 11:30:00')
```

But I'm getting:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'from, to, time) VALUES (12345,'blah','test','2012-12-13 11:3' at line 1
```

The query seems fine to me, what is wrong with it?

Comment: It's not possible. It's likely you run another query, not the one you've shown to us

Comment: @zerkms: yea, the name of fields were different. The answers below fixed it, edited question now to show the correct field names.

Comment: well from is an reserved word

Comment: FROM is reserved word!!! :) Escape it with `

Comment: @houbysoft This is bad manner : you show us a query which doesn't show the problem so the first random (and badly informed) answer happen to solve it... Please be more careful (test) when asking. Anyway, thanks for making it clear afterwards.

Comment: Yea stupid mistake, I see it now, thanks :)

Comment: you're using a reserved word (from) and a function (time) as table column names - that is not a very wise idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use backticks on your fields to prevent a conflict with MySQL reserved words:

```
INSERT INTO table_a (`fb_uid`, `from`, `to`, `time`) VALUES (12345,'blah','test','2012-12-13 11:30:00')
```

**In this case, `from` and `to` are the reserved words**

[See here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) for more information and a complete list of reserved words.

Comment: Which one is reserved in this query? Not an answer.

Comment: I deleted my wrong comment about 'time'. Anyway - i never use so short column names, because of reserved words. Maybe use "something_to" and "something_from" instead, to avoid these errors in future.

Comment: @Kamil: personally I give the most meaningful name regardless if it's reserved or not. Readability of the scheme is much more important than saving 2 keystrokes :-)

Comment: I know, but that damn ` key is in awkward place... In MS-SQL im using your rule, im even using spaces in object names (!), because there are [] (square brackets?) instead of that finger-twisting button :)

Answer (score 1):

`FROM` and `TO` are reserved keyword,

```
INSERT INTO table_a (fb_uid, `from`, `to`, time)....
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keyword List](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Answer (score 0):

time is a restricted word, does this help:

```
INSERT INTO table_a (`fb_uid`, `x`, `y`, `time`) VALUES (12345,'blah','test','2012-12-13 11:30:00')
```

Escaping everything to be sure.

Comment: I don't think so : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html (see at end)